# passport.authenticate dies a silent death

Tags: node.js, express, passport-local

So trying to create a local strategy for users to sign up, quite simple front end, four fields; User name, email, password (and then password again, because its in the form). I know that the post works, the following information is sent as part of it

```
username:user
email:user@test.com
password:IAMPASSWORD
passwordConfirm:IAMPASSWORD
```

I then use what I understand is a very simple passport.authenticate (OK, I think it should be simple, but clearly not THAT simple).

```
var cfgWebPage = require('../config/webpage.js')


module.exports = function(app, passport) {
    /* GET home page. */
    app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
        res.render('index', {title: 'Express'});
    });


    //This is signup
    app.get('/signup', function(req, res) {

        // render the page and pass in any flash data if it exists
        res.render('signup.ejs', { title: 'Sign up to our service' , loginUrl: cfgWebPage.loginUrl, trackingID: cfgWebPage.googleTracking.trackingID, message: req.flash('signupMessage') });
    });
    // process the signup form
    app.post('/signup',  passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
        successRedirect : '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
        failureRedirect : '/signup', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
        failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
    }));
}
```

And it definitely gets this far, (changed it for a console.log message just to test).

I get a response back from the server that it does a 302, and it behaves as if it has failed, but nothing in the console.

```
// required for passport
app.use(session({secret: 'Thisisnottherealone',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
})); // session secret
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
app.use(flash()); // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session
//Configuring the passports
require('./config/passport')(passport);


var routes = require('./routes/index')(app, passport);
```

1. So it finds the passport, I am guessing - would have expected it to
   complain otherwise.
2. It seems to call authenticate - No errors there

I have tried to change things in the passport.js file (contains my passport settings for sign-up) but it never seems to get that far, seems to die sometime after that database is opened. 
Here is the passport.js file (from config)

```
// config/passport.js

// load up the user model
var LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy;

// load up the user model
var mysql = require('mysql');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var dbconfig = require('./database');
var sqlConnection = mysql.createConnection(dbconfig.sqlConnection);


sqlConnection.query('USE ' + dbconfig.sqlDatabase);

// expose this function to our app using module.exports
module.exports = function(passport, app) {

    // =========================================================================
    // passport session setup ==================================================
    // =========================================================================
    // required for persistent login sessions
    // passport needs ability to serialize and unserialize users out of session

    // used to serialize the user for the session
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    // used to deserialize the user
    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
//        User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
//            done(err, user);
//       });
        passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
            console.log('deserialising');
            sqlConnection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ? ",[id], function(err, rows){
                done(err, rows[0]);
            });
        });
    });

    // =========================================================================
    // LOCAL SIGNUP ============================================================
    // =========================================================================
    // we are using named strategies since we have one for login and one for signup
    // by default, if there was no name, it would just be called 'local'

    passport.use(
        'local-signup',
        new LocalStrategy({
                // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
                emailField : 'email',
                usernameField : 'username',
                passwordField : 'password',
                passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
            },
            function(req, username, email, password, done) {
                // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
                // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
                console.log("Calling database!");
                sqlConnection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?",[username], function(err, rows) {
                    if (err)
                        return done(err);
                    if (rows.length) {
                        return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That username is already taken.'));
                    } else {
                        // if there is no user with that username
                        // create the user
                        var newUserMysql = {
                            username: username,
                            email: email,
                            password: bcrypt.hashSync(password, null, null)  // use the generateHash function in our user model
                        };

                        var insertQuery = "INSERT INTO users ( username, email, password ) values (?,?)";

                        sqlConnection.query(insertQuery,[newUserMysql.username, newUserMysql.password],function(err, rows) {
                            newUserMysql.id = rows.insertId;

                            return done(null, newUserMysql);
                        });
                    }
                });
            })
    );

};
```

Any suggestions where the issue is, or easiest way to debug it?

Comment: In the end the issue was quite simple.

Answer (score 1):

In the end the issue was simple, and nothing to do with passport.

I had missed to decode the incoming data. 
Add the following and bobs your uncle (sending a passport.authenticate without any user info makes passport sad and makes it die all in silence).

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');



module.exports = function(app, passport) {
    var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false})
    /* GET home page. */
```

==== Example of API call =====

```
 app.post('/login', urlencodedParser, passport.authenticate('local-login', {
        successRedirect : '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
        failureRedirect : '/login', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
        failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
    }));
```

Comment: passport.authenticate is failing silently for me

Comment: You initiate it as above,  then you pass it as part of the function  call.  I'll post an example.

Comment: Alex: Added the login call I use above, note app.post('/login', urlencodedParser .  It will call urlencodedParser on the way and return (or populate) req with the necessary information. Passport seems happy to read it this way.

Comment: thanks, couls you not also do - var bodyParser = require(body-parser); app.use(bodyParser());)